# Set value of sfwidgetformdoctrinechoice from a parameter

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

Is there any way to set the value of a sfwidgetformdoctrinechoice from the parameter in actions.php?

I know I could change it into a sfWidgetInput instead, but I want the user to be able to be able to choose a record if no parameter is given.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes!
In the `configure()` method of your form use the `setDefaults()` method:

```
public function configure()
{  
    $this->setDefaults(array( 
    'your_widget' => 'your_parameter'
    ));
}
```

or, more simply, in your action code

```
$form = new YourForm(array('your_parameter'=> 'your_parameter_value'))
```

which is easy to understand when you see this:

```
  /**  
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param array  $defaults    An array of field default values
   * @param array  $options     An array of options
   * @param string $CSRFSecret  A CSRF secret
   */
  public function __construct($defaults = array(), $options = array(), $CSRFSecret = null)
  {
    $this->setDefaults($defaults);
    ...
```

Comment: but how would you get the parameter from the address into the configure method?

Comment: Thanks for all your help but I'm still getting an error: "The "sessionForm" form only accepts a "session" object." 

my actions file contains: [code]  public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  { 
 $this->form = new sessionForm(array('slideshow_id' => $request->getParameter('slideshow')));
  }

Comment: @dazpinto: Regarding Doctrine forms, the defaults argument is not an array, but an object. Create a default object, initialize it with your parameter, and pass it to the constructor, and you should be done.